# The attributes disappear after setting the appearance of UIBarButtonItem in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiappearance

I'm trying to customize the appearance of all `UIBarButtonItem` instances in the initialize function of `UINavigationController`.

```
+ (void)initialize {
    UIBarButtonItem *item = [UIBarButtonItem appearance];

    NSMutableDictionary *attrs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    attrs[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = [UIColor orangeColor];
    attrs[NSFontAttributeName] = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    [item setTitleTextAttributes:attrs forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSMutableDictionary *disableAttrs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    disableAttrs[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    disableAttrs[NSFontAttributeName] = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    [item setTitleTextAttributes:disableAttrs forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
}
```

The appearance of `UIViewController's` `UIBarButtonItem` is correct when the `UINavigationController` is the `UITabBarController's` child controller.It's orange when enabled and lightGray when disabled.  But the appearance is wrong when using presentViewController when click the button.

```
- (void)tabBarDidClickPlusButton:(UITabBar *)tabBar {

   ComposeViewController *cmpVC = [[ComposeViewController alloc] init];
   WBNavigationController *nvc = [[WBNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cmpVC];
   [self presentViewController:nvc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

The `UIBarButtonItem` is still orange when disabled.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

I print the Attributes and find out they are all (null).

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateNormal]);
NSLog(@"%@", [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateDisabled]);
```

Any idea why this happens?
Much appreciated.

I try to set the attribute to the instance of UIBarButtonItem in viewDidLoad,but it still doesn't work.The color is still not gray.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"send" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(send)];
NSMutableDictionary *disableAttrs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
disableAttrs[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:disableAttrs forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: try using UIAppearance protocol: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/

Comment: I did use UIAppearance protocol, but it did not work well. [UIBarButtonItem appearance]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see. Did you try AppearanceWhenContainedIn:

Comment: I did,but no difference. And i find that this only happens when using "presentViewController" to modal a navigationController. The Attributes don't work in the  navigationController's rootViewController. The color is right when i push the viewController using "pushViewController" in a navigationController.Strange, right?

Comment: Are you sure you targeted your ComposeViewController? (AppearanceWhenContainedIn:[ComposeViewController class])

Comment: Well, "appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[ComposeViewController class]]"does work! But why? Doesn't [UIBarButtonItem appearance] affect all the instances of UIBarButtonItems? So i have to add all classes in appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses if i want  all UIBarButtonItems have the same appearance?

Comment: I guess it happens only with modal views, I don't know why